# Is a pointer which is a private member of a linked list allocated on heap?

Tags: c++, memory, linked-list

I'm trying to understand how is the pointer which is the private member of a linked list allocated.
Let's say I have the following design:

```
class LinkedList
{
private:
    ListNode* m_ptrHead{ nullptr };
}

class ListNode
{
private:
    ListNode* m_ptrNext;
    int       m_data;
}
```

Anytime, I want to add a node to an instance of the linked list, I need to dynamically allocate a new ListNode object on the heap and update the next pointer of the last node to point to this object. My questions are:

1. Since the newly created object is on the heap, is it m_ptrNext also on the heap?
2. If the m_ptrNext is on stack, how can the object knows about m_ptrNext's existance?

Comment: The pointer is *part of* the object. It's like asking, if an int is on the heap, are its bits also on the heap? If my car is in the garage, is its exhaust pipe also in the garage? If my car is on the street, how can the car know about the exhaust pipe's existence?

Answer (score 0):

These are strange questions.

The pointer is *part* of the object. All of the variables of `ListNode` are inside each ListNode object. (Each ListNode object its own separate copies of these variables)

> 1. Since the newly created object is on the heap, is it m_ptrNext also on the heap?

Yes. All the object's variables are inside the object.

> 2. If the m_ptrNext is on stack, how can the object knows about m_ptrNext's existance?

... all the object's variables are inside the object.

If an object is a car, its variables are the car parts.
If the car is in the garage, is its exhaust pipe also in the garage? (answer: yes. duh)
If the car is on the street, how does it know about its exhaust pipe's existence? (answer: ...)